# FFMPEG encoding is rotating portrait images uploaded from the iPhone

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I'm trying to figure out why FFMPEG is rotating my thumbnail image when a portrait video is uploaded from an iphone.

Here is my command line test:

```
ffmpeg -i video/test.mp4 -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -level 5 -crf 18 -preset medium -maxrate 10M -bufsize 16M -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=iw*sar:ih, scale=\'if(gt(iw,ih),min(1920,iw),-1)\':\'if(gt(iw,ih),-1,min(1080,ih))\'" -x264opts bframes=3:cabac=1 -movflags faststart -b:a 320k -y video/test.mp4 -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 410x231 video/testthumb.jpg 2>&1
```

Then the portrait image is rotated 90 degrees to be made a landscape image, but the video stays portrait. How can I keep the orientation the same?

Comment: `ffmpeg` will automatically rotate the output according to the input rotation sidedata. See the `-noautorotate` option if you want to disable this behavior. No need for `-vcodec mjpeg -an -f rawvideo`.

Comment: Is it? But has `-s 410x231` made sure it is a landscape one?

Comment: In a way, yes, but 1) it may simply be distorted to fit depending on the input parameters, and 2) the image viewer may not pay attention to the resulting SAR meaning various viewers can display it differently (`ffplay` vs Firefox for example).

Comment: did u find any solution for this?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?